# Install xap file on windows phone from inside an application

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I try to install a windows phone application from inside an application using this code

```
Uri FILE_URI = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/myapp.xap",UriKind.Absolute);
await InstallationManager.AddPackageAsync("my app", FILE_URI);
```

but it return

```
 global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

i try to use

```
Uri FILE_URI = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/myapp.xap",UriKind.Absolute);
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(FILE_URI);
await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
```

but the windows phone error happened

Can't install company app
there's a problem with this company app.
Contact your company's support person for help.

how can I install xap file from inside application? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Little information ...

There are several causes of the problem:

1) your xap file is downloaded contains the signature Windows store? I.e. you published your app Store and downloaded the install file for?

2) You trying are enterprise application scenario with self-signed XAP file?

3) As i'm understand it, the method is intended for `AddPackageAsync. InstallationManager` installing applications from external sources as "http//...". I'm not sure what method the XAP has installed from a local storage.

4) Installing the application that is downloaded from the Windows store are available from the SD card. I think that there are restrictions on the installation of the XAP file from local storage.

5) Known problem when InstallationManager. AddPackageAsync does not work on the emulator, but works on the device. [Error code '0x800703F0' for Signed internal App while using InstallationManager](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e88562de-ba55-4376-a282-acca313cbb77/getting-error-code-0x800703f0-for-signed-internal-app-while-using?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: maybe you know how to install xap file that was saved from ms store ?